# Convert Access Crosstab Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I have a crosstab query in MS Access which runs very slow after migrating my backend to an SQL Server 2017. So I want to create a view in SQL that does the same aggregation.

MS Access Query:

```
TRANSFORM Sum([Auftrag Positionen].Gesamtpreis) AS SummevonGesamtpreis
SELECT Format$([Stammdaten Datum].[Datum],'yyyy\/mm    mmmm') AS Monat, Sum([Auftrag Positionen].Gesamtpreis) AS Gesamt
FROM [Stammdaten Datum] LEFT JOIN (Auftrag LEFT JOIN ([Stammdaten Statistik] RIGHT JOIN [Auftrag Positionen] ON [Stammdaten Statistik].Kennzeichen = [Auftrag Positionen].Statistik) ON Auftrag.[Auftrags-Nummer] = [Auftrag Positionen].[Auftrags-Nummer]) ON [Stammdaten Datum].Datum = Auftrag.Auftragseingang
WHERE (((Auftrag.[Auftrag-Angebot])="Auftrag"))
GROUP BY Format$([Stammdaten Datum].[Datum],'yyyy\/mm    mmmm')
ORDER BY Format$([Stammdaten Datum].[Datum],'yyyy\/mm    mmmm') DESC 
PIVOT [Stammdaten Statistik].Beschreibung;
```

I get that I can cancel out the access date formatting:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Stammdaten Datum].[Datum]), 0) AS Monat, Sum([Auftrag Positionen].Gesamtpreis) AS Gesamt
FROM [ROBI_1].[dbo].[Stammdaten Datum] LEFT JOIN ([ROBI_1].[dbo].Auftrag LEFT JOIN (ROBI_1.dbo.[Stammdaten Statistik] RIGHT JOIN ROBI_1.dbo.[Auftrag Positionen] ON [Stammdaten Statistik].Kennzeichen = [Auftrag Positionen].Statistik) ON Auftrag.[Auftrags-Nummer] = [Auftrag Positionen].[Auftrags-Nummer]) ON [ROBI_1].[dbo].[Stammdaten Datum].Datum = Auftrag.Auftragseingang
WHERE ((([Auftrag].[Auftrag-Angebot])='Auftrag'))
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Stammdaten Datum].[Datum]), 0)
ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [Stammdaten Datum].[Datum]), 0) DESC
```

But I don't know how to do the pivot aggregation, everything I've tried gave me syntax errors. (I am a noob in SQL/T-SQL indeed).
I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please get in the habit of making good use of line breaks and white space; it makes your code far more readable. Also, is there a reason you're nesting your `ON` clauses? There rarely a need to do that (in T-SQL).

Comment: T-SQL does not allow a variable number of column names like Access does. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37041634/7296893) for an example on how to translate, but you really want to do the pivotting in Access. You can create a pivot query off  of the T-SQL query you've already created using a passthrough query.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be something like this:

```
;WITH   MonatGesamt AS 
    (
        SELECT
                    Monat       =   DATEPART(MONTH, SD.Datum)
                ,   Gesamtpreis =   ISNULL(AP.Gesamtpreis, 0)

        FROM        ROBI_1.dbo.[Stammdaten Datum]       SD      
        LEFT JOIN   ROBI_1.dbo.Auftrag                  AT  ON  AT.Auftragseingang      =   SD.Datum
        LEFT JOIN   ROBI_1.dbo.[Auftrag Positionen]     AP  ON  AP.[Auftrags-Nummer]    =   AT.[Auftrags-Nummer]
     
        WHERE       AT.[Auftrag-Angebot]    =   'Auftrag'
    )
    
SELECT  
            Monat   
        ,   Gesamt  =   SUM(Gesamtpreis)
FROM        MonatGesamt
GROUP BY    Monat
ORDER BY    Monat   DESC
```